# undefined reference to `dlopen' when building libircclient with ssl enabled

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile libircclient with ssl enabled

```
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto"
export CPATH=/usr/local/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
./configure --enable-openssl --enable-ipv6
```

But I get the error

> undefined reference to `dlopen'

This is my build log

```
user@nano:~/luaTest/thirdparty/libircclient-1.8$ export LDFLAGS="-ldl -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto"
user@nano:~/luaTest/thirdparty/libircclient-1.8$ export CPATH=/usr/local/includeuser@nano:~/luaTest/thirdparty/libircclient-1.8$ export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
user@nano:~/luaTest/thirdparty/libircclient-1.8$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
user@nano:~/luaTest/thirdparty/libircclient-1.8$ ./configure --enable-openssl --enable-ipv6
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking types of arguments for select... int,fd_set *,struct timeval *
checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... yes
checking whether stat accepts an empty string... no
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for getaddrinfo... yes
checking for inet_pton... yes
checking for getaddrinfo in -lnsl... yes
checking For MinGW32... no
checking for CRYPTO_new_ex_data in -lcrypto... no
configure: error: OpenSSL not found
user@nano:~/luaTest/thirdparty/libircclient-1.8$ make
for subdir in src examples; do \
        make -C $subdir || exit 1; \
    done
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/luaTest/thirdparty/libircclient-1.8/src'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/luaTest/thirdparty/libircclient-1.8/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/luaTest/thirdparty/libircclient-1.8/examples'
gcc -o spammer spammer.o -L../src/ -lircclient -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto  -lnsl
/usr/local/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `dlopen'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `dlsym'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_func':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x33b): undefined reference to `dlsym'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x410): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_var':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x48b): undefined reference to `dlsym'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x566): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_load':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x5e0): undefined reference to `dlopen'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x658): undefined reference to `dlclose'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x69d): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_pathbyaddr':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x736): undefined reference to `dladdr'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x821): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_unload':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x87e): undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [spammer] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/luaTest/thirdparty/libircclient-1.8/examples'
make: *** [all] Error 1
user@nano:~/luaTest/thirdparty/libircclient-1.8$
```

Answer (score -1):

It is quite clear that the sample program from the `examples` subdirectory is not getting linked with libdl. That link command makes it quite clear.

You explicitly set `LDFLAGS` in the environment to include the "-ldl" flag, before running `configure`, so the problem is that the makefile that's responsible for building this test program is not picking up the manual `LDFLAGS` setting.

So, really, that's what the problem is. Your next step is to try to figure out why, by yourself. Of course, you might get lucky and someone around here would be nice enough to grab this package themselves, and figure it out for you.

But, if you're actually looking to learn something from this experience, you should do it yourself. Go look at the actual makefile that builds it, see what command is used to link the program, what variables it's using, and then, figure out what needs to be done to make this part of this application link correctly.

This is an excellent opportunity for you to learn all about the GNU toolchain that's obviously used here: `autoconf`, `automake`, and `libtool`. And, once you do that, you'll be able to figure out and work with not just this particular software package, but with thousands and thousands of other free software packages that also use the GNU toolchain. I'm sure you will agree that this would be a very useful skill to have. It might take some time for you to read through all the documentation, understand it, and learn how to use it, but you'll be able to take this knowledge with you, and use it many times in the future.

Comment: If i set the flags after configure I get the same error, the problem persists

Comment: I understand. Now, did you look at the Makefile, as I suggested, to see what it uses to generate the link command?

Comment: i removed the examples directory from the make file and it just says no target specified for make file and stopped

Comment: Entering directory `/home/user/luaTest/thirdparty/libircclient-1.8/src'
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

Comment: Of course. In general, removing random parts of code is not very likely to solve any problems. But I never suggested that removing the examples directory will fix anything. It's possible that there might be a configure option to skip building the examples directory, that might be a good way of avoiding the problem. But, as I said, you will not solve this problem in any other way other than looking at the Makefile in question, and fixing it. Take it from someone who, some time ago, had to figure out why gcc's own makefile craps out, and doesn't build itself.

Comment: there is a makefile.in inside the src directory but it doesnt seem to see it

Comment: Of course not. make reads Makefile, not Makefile.in. Makefile.in is the template that autoconf uses to build the real Makefile. As I wrote in my answer: go and learn how the GNU toolchain -- autoconf, automake, and libtool -- works. If you don't understand how the build toolchain works, you have little chance of figuring out build problems. libircclient isn't the only package that uses them, thousands of other free software packages use them too. Learning how to use them is a necessary skill if one expects to actually make a living doing this kind of work.

Comment: Please pay attention to this error message: `configure: error: OpenSSL not found`. It means your configure did not complete. Thus, you should not rely that the makefiles are made correctly to build the SW.

Comment: @dmi - the fact that configure reports that a particular component is not found does not, in itself, mean that the configuration failed. If it did, configure would not've produced an actual makefile, and nothing could be built. Which is clearly not the case here. It is quite normal to have the configure script test for various components, enable the corresponding application options if they're found, and leave them out if not. Furthermore, the issue here is not with openssl, but with libdl, so it's unlikely that openssl has anything to do with this.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik. I have not stated the OpenSSL is a root cause. I only pointed out that the configure was interrupted and not clear what could be the consequences. From this perspective the build may not be consistent (i.e. you may have several libdl versions or something like that what is supposed to be detected after the error if the configure would continue).